# How to change a field on a sub-form depending on a value of a record

Tags: ms-access

I have a product table with 2 different price for each product. In customer table I have a price category for each customer. When I open the order form, I choose the customer from a drop down list and the field of pricecategory show the type that the current customer has (1 or 2).

I tried to transfer the value of pricecategory to sub-form but I can't handle how to change the control source of the price field. Probably this approach doesn't work. How can I complete this task? I need the logic structure.

I tried with IIf statement in the control source with no success.
`iif([forms]![Orders]![PriceCategory]=1,[Price1], iff([forms]![Orders]![PriceCategory]=2,[Price2]))`

I try to find a way to change the control source from price1 to price2 in the field of a sub-form. Actually I want to automatically change the price field depending on the customer.

Thanks

Comment: Include the price fields as columns in combobox. Then condtional expression can reference columns of combobox. For a report, RecordSource would include related tables and your IIf() expression would refer to fields. Not changing the ControlSource. If you want to save the price value into order record, that would require VBA.

Comment: Thanks for response, I tried to use combobox but this show me the tow price side by side (probably I'm doing something wrong). I tried with VBA in form: Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
Dim x As Integer, Pr As Text
x = PC              'PC is the name of PriceCategory field
If x = 2 Then
    Pr = "Price2"
Else
    Pr = "Price1"
End If
Price.ControlSource = Pr
End Sub    -  But doesn't work

Comment: The price columns can be hidden if you don't want user to see. Should edit your question with info so readers don't have to wade through comments. Don't use AfterInsert, use combobox AfterUpdate and reference columns of combobox. The Price fields should not even be available to reference directly.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, for now I use tabbed sub-form for each price category (tow tables, tow subforms, tow report for printing etc).